# Elastic search for mutliple fields in indexed data

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, npm

I am using monogsastic npm for my elastic search in node js. I wanted to query on more than one field.The condition that I want to use is either this field or that field.

I was successfull in searching using one field

```
var userfollowers =['5c5bbc7c18425d3f440e82aa','5c5f7ef118425d3f440f5cec','5c6c22820c384e6f2cd65f31','5ca11df654572d6b67998591','5c9e296054572d6b6798f2bf','5ca2f87ee9131074001491b5','5ca1d1d554572d6b6799cb51'];
var topics = [ 'adaptive signal processing','amplifiers','biomedical equipment','business','chemical technology','imaging'];

    Paperupload.esSearch({ 
            from:from,
                    size:size,
                            query:{
                                    "terms" : {
                                    "userId._id": userfollowers
                                    }

                            },
                            sort:{
                                "createdAt":{
                                    "order" : "desc"
                                }
                            }   
                },
                function(err, results) {
                    console.log("err",err)
                    console.log("result:",results)
                }
```

Need to also search for topics in content field of indexed data.Condition to be applied is OR (either userFollowers OR topics in content)

Comment: No worries I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Paperupload.esSearch({      
                    query:{
                            bool:{
                                        "must": {
                                            "bool" : { "should": [{terms : {"userId._id": followersDetail}},{terms : {"topics.topic_name": topi}}] }
                                        }
                             }
                            },          
                            sort:{
                                "createdAt":{
                                    "order" : "desc"
                                }
                            }   
                    },
                    {
                        from:from,
                        size:size,
                    },
                    function(err, results) {

                    })
```

Comment: Add many more condtions in should and you will get the results